# Setting up Google Authentication with Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin, google-authentication

I am using default template provided by Asp.Net MVC-5. Enabled Google authentication. My local site takes me to google authentication page. However on succesful authentication when google redirects back, I get below error:

> The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted

I double checked and trusted IIS Express site explicitly.

P.S. I had followed each and every step correctly from [this article](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864)

Comment: Sounds like the HTTPS certificate that is running your local site is not trusted in your browser. It's probably because it's self signed. If it's `localhost` it's semi-expected since no legitimate certificate authority is going to sign a certificate for `localhost`.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but FYI Google Open ID 2.0 is now deprecated: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID2

Answer (score 0):

Here is this video step by step
[youtube link to video on google authentication for mvc in dotnet5 command line setup...](https://youtu.be/GF0Mn-g7Nf0)

first go here and create your credentials...:  [https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials\](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials%5C)

then commandline time:

```
dotnet new mvc -o MyApplicationName --auth Individual
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google
dotnet user-secrets init
dotnet user-secrets set "Authentication:Google:ClientId" <MyClientIDSecret>
dotnet user-secrets set "Authentication:Google:ClientSecret" <MyClientSecret>
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI
dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
dotnet ef database update
```

then open in visual studio or vs code and change the code:

just above addControllersWithViews:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddGoogle(options =>
            {
                IConfigurationSection googleAuthNSection =
                    Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Google");

                options.ClientId = googleAuthNSection["ClientId"];
                options.ClientSecret = googleAuthNSection["ClientSecret"];
            });
```

add [Authorize] to home controller
add [Allowanonymous] to index

Comment: @Blastfurnace I have put the code from the video into the post instead, is that better?